# Ubuntu 23.10.1 ISO Installer, and runaway python3 process

Tags: python3, iso, 23.10

I prepared an external 2TB USB SSD drive with the (re-released) 23.10.1 ISO image. Then I edited /etc/grub.d/40-custom to be able to boot to the ISO image directly from GRUB.

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 23.10.1 Desktop ISO (external disk)" {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        rmmod tpm
        set gfxpayload=keep
        set root=(hd0,gpt1)
        set isofile="/ubuntu-23.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper layerfs-path=minimal.standard.live.squashfs iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet splash
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

However, when I boot to it, it starts with the Ubuntu Installer in INSTALL mode, and I quit the Installer by clicking on the close "x" button, my fans get very accelerated, and a `top` command indicates that python3 is at 100%.

I let it run for quite a while, hoping that it would settle down on its own, but it didn't, so I killed the process (without any apparent side effects).

This behavior is repeatable.

Anybody else notice similar behavior? Know what's going on? Is there a fix?

---

**Update #1**: The pre-23.10.1 installers USED to come up with either "TRY Ubuntu", or "INSTALL Ubuntu". This "new" installer only comes up in INSTALL mode. If you click on the close "x" button, the installer quits, but then the python3 process runs amok.

`cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline` shows:

/snap/ubuntu-desktop-installer/1267/usr/bin/python3.10-msubiquity.cmd.server--use-os-prober--storage-version=2--postinst-hooks-dir=/snap/ubuntu-desktop-installer/1267/etc/subiquity/postinst.d

You can `sudo kill -HUP <pid>` and the process goes away, and the fans spin back down.

Looks like an Installer bug.

---

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149266/discussion-on-question-by-heynnema-ubuntu-23-10-1-iso-installer-and-runaway-pyt); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @andrew.46 I moved it to chat many hours ago.

Comment: Oops my apologies!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there's a difference, when booting 23.10.1 from DVD, vs booting the 23.10.1 ISO image via GRUB, when it's been copied to a 2TB USB SSD drive.

When booting to a DVD, the GRUB menu asks if you wish to "TRY or INSTALL Ubuntu".

When booting to the ISO image on a 2TB USB SSD drive, from GRUB, it just goes directly into the Ubuntu Installer in INSTALL mode. If you click the close "x" button, the Installer quits, but leaves behind a runaway Python process at 100% of CPU. This Python process can be killed.

Installer bug.